# Angular model doesn't update when changing input programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input bound to a model value, but I can't figure out how to change the input value programmatically and have the change propagate to the model.

I understand that because I'm updating the value external to the angular scope that I need to explicitly call `$scope.$apply()`, but it's not working.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="test_input" ng-model="test_value">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.test_value = 'abc'; // starting value
```

**Console:**

```
$('#test_input').val('xyz');
$('#test_input').scope().$apply();
$('#test_input').scope().test_value;
-> 'abc';
```

Comment: Why are you not changing the value of $scope.test_value directly using console and rather doing it using jquery?

Comment: @RahulArora - This is demo code. I have an app where the input element is being updated programmatically, and I want the model to register that.

Comment: Check my answer @Yarin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ngModel listens for "input" event, so you need to trigger that event after setting the value:

```
$('#test_input').val('xyz');
$('#test_input').trigger('input'); 
$('#test_input').scope().test_value;
```

Comment: Side note: You do not need the `$apply()` call when using `trigger`,  and jQuery has to be included before Angular in order for it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/xj9rysy6/

Comment: What if I'm working in an 'input' event? wouldn't triggering the input again cause an infinite loop?

Comment: then you dont need to trigger it, you just need to call the scope() for angular to digest it